# Error with WCF configuration for MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am getting the following error when calling my service;

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

The configuration of the service is;

```
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basic" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="67108864" maxArrayLength="10240000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Company.Product.Service.FileManager.IFileManager">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basic" name="FileManager" bindingNamespace="Company.Product.FileManager.FileManagerService" contract="Company.Product.Service.FileManager.IFileManager" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://filemanager.dev.v7.services.Company.net" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

As you can see, I have adjusted the settings accordingly, so not sure why I am still getting this error.

Client Configuration;

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basic" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="67108864" maxArrayLength="10240000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint address="http://filemanager.dev.v7.services.Company.net/service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basic" contract="Company.Product.Service.FileManager.IFileManager" name="FileManager"/>
    </client>
```

**Update**

Changing the service configuration to this (removed the binding name) and this now works, but why would it not work with a named configuration;

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="67108864" maxArrayLength="10240000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but are you sure it is not a client config problem?

Comment: The client sees a 400 error and the exception is thrown by the service, visible through it's tracing. The client also has an identical binding configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the app.config of your client as well.

Edit:

If you leave the name attribute empty it will be applied to every binding of the type that is not named. If you have a named binding in the config it will only be picked up if it is explicitly referenced by that name.

Comment: The client has an identical configuration, as per my comment. Added to original question.

Comment: That's the thing, it was explicitly referenced as far as I can see.